# How do I disable an app from running at startup

Tags: auto-start

I have a genymotion virtual device which has an app which runs at startup which make the device crash giving me no access to the device.

How do I disable the app from my computer. (I am using virtual device)?

Answer (score 1):

There are many options available. Some applications I know:

1. Comoro mobile security
2. Autostarts
3. ES Task Manager
4. BootManager (a module works within XPosed framework)

Autostarts also let you stop waking applications which listen on events I.e. when device gets connected to internet or a call is answered.

Comment: I cant access my device in the first place forget install an app in it